# Want to redirect to wildcard subdomain without changing url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect a wildcard sub-domain without changing the url.
For example, If user types subdomain.domain.com I want it to go to www.domain.com/subdomain but not change the original url.  Both domain and subdomain are in root folder.

I have tried many examples to get this working and have come up with the below htaccess code to redirect to a wildcard sub-domain. This code will re-direct user to proper wildcard subdomain but the resulting url does not change. If user types in subdomain.domain.com the url changes to www.domain.com/subdomain.

I'm on a shared hosting plan with GoDaddy and I have a dedicated IP. This is the makeup of my root folder:

```
Root->
domain -> subdomain1, subdomain2 etc
domain2
domain3
domain4
.htaccess
welcome.html
```

The subdomain folders are created using code when the user requests to create there own site. This is what I had tried originally in my htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/%1 [NC]
```

After trying the suggested answer below and typing in subdomain.domain.com I am now directed to what looks like an internal GoDaddy screen that says 'Future home of something quite cool'. What kind of changes to do I need to make to my htaccess or is what I'm asking for even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %1#$1 !^([^#]+)#\1
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for offering this solution. The url is staying the same but the website isn't loading. I'm not sure if it matters but I'm on a shared hosting plan with GoDaddy. The url www.domain.com/subdomain works just fine.

Comment: Does the URL subdomain.domain.com/subdomain work? If not, then they **aren't** pointing to the same root, and you'll need to change your configuration such that they are, or point it to the subdomain folder

Comment: No. Internal Server Error when I try subdomain.domain.com/subdomain. But www.domain.com/subdomain still works though.

Comment: What kind of changes would I need to make to my configuration or how to point to subdomain folder?

Comment: @JonLin Just one typo with `[#^]` -> `[^#]`

Comment: Changed the typo. I think getting closer. I get this error message: 'The requested URL /subdomain/welcome.html was not found on this server.' domain is a folder in my root and subdomain is in domain folder. I have welcome.html file in my root.

Comment: @user3287677 try with the added 2 conditions

Comment: Tried with extra conditions and I don't get the error message any more but I get the 'Future home of something cool' page.